# How to fix "current directory" change in SVN?

Tags: svn

My `svn status` shows a change in current directory like this,

```
$ svn status
!       .
```

It won't go away after either `svn commit` or `svn revert`.

How should I fix that?

**EDIT**

No it does not work with `svn cleanup`.

Comment: Have you tried `svn cleanup`?

Comment: Just tried that, not working tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens after setting svn properties for the current folder. To fix this, run `svn up`.

Comment: I was suspecting permission or ownership, but since this is a fresh checkout it just don't make any sense. By running `svn up` it turns out I have some files deep inside the trunk requires updating, not sure what was changed tho. It just works.

Comment: Maybe someone changed the ignore pattern.